# how to combine two arrays of different types and put them as a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

I have two numpy arrays as following

```
A = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3] #integers
B = ['xx','xx','xx','yy','yy','yy','zz','zz''zz'] #strings
```

that I want to combine and store as a list such as:

```
AB_list = [[1,'xx'],[2,'xx'],[3,'xx'],[1,'yy'],[2,'yy'],[3,'yy'],[1,'zz'],[2,'zz'],[3,'zz'],]
```

Anyone could help ?

Comment: Have a look at the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this using list comprehension and the zip iterator should work:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]) #integers
B = np.array(['xx','xx','xx','yy','yy','yy','zz','zz','zz'])
[ [a,b] for a,b in zip(A,B) ]
Out[29]: 
[[1, 'xx'],
 [2, 'xx'],
 [3, 'xx'],
 [1, 'yy'],
 [2, 'yy'],
 [3, 'yy'],
 [1, 'zz'],
 [2, 'zz'],
 [3, 'zz']]
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly , you are missing a comma in your List 'B'

```
B = ['xx','xx','xx','yy','yy','yy','zz','zz','zz']
```

After fixing it ,You can use column_stack to get the desired result

```
import numpy as np    
A = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
B = ['xx','xx','xx','yy','yy','yy','zz','zz','zz']

np.column_stack((A, B))
```

Output:

```
array([['1', 'xx'],
       ['2', 'xx'],
       ['3', 'xx'],
       ['1', 'yy'],
       ['2', 'yy'],
       ['3', 'yy'],
       ['1', 'zz'],
       ['2', 'zz'],
       ['3', 'zz']], dtype='<U21')
```

Comment: This is incorrect because it changes the type of the integers

Comment: Agreed , missed on it. @talonmies solution works well